ORA-01403: no data found in Oracle plsql procedure
One row of data exists for each combination of project_id and task number, but it is throwing no data found error.
SELECT INTO throws error, but just a select with where clause is fetching one row of data.
Here is the procedure:
PROCEDURE GET_TASK_ID(P_TASK_NUMBER_IN IN VARCHAR2,
   P_PROJ_ID_IN NUMBER,
   P_TASK_ID_OUT OUT NUMBER) IS
   L_TASK_ID_OUT NUMBER;
BEGIN
   G_PROC_NAME := 'GET_TASK_ID';
   G_ERR_LOCATION := '10';

   BEGIN
       SELECT TASK_ID INTO L_TASK_ID_OUT
       FROM PA_TASKS
       WHERE PROJECT_ID = P_PROJ_ID_IN
         AND TASK_NUMBER = P_TASK_NUMBER_IN
         AND CHARGEABLE_FLAG = 'Y';
   P_TASK_ID_OUT := L_TASK_ID_OUT;

I think the task_number has a new line character.
Replace and translate functions are not working for my scenario. Any leads here please?

It would be clearer if you included exact values that you are passing to your procedure and results of your SQL statement that is returning a row.
Without them, my only guess might be that your database column task_number in your table PA_TASKS may contain values either with leading or trailing spaces. Or as you said new line character. In that case, i suggest using trim functions (trim, rtrim, ltrim) in your where clause on your task_number column

Outside of the procedure, run:
SELECT TASK_ID,
       TASK_NUMBER,
       DUMP(TASK_NUMBER)
FROM   PA_TASKS
WHERE  PROJECT_ID      = :your_expected_project_id
AND    TASK_NUMBER     LIKE :your_expected_task_number || '%'
AND    CHARGEABLE_FLAG = 'Y';

(Passing the appropriate values via the bind variables.)
And DUMP will show you the byte values in the task number which will let you see if there is a space, carriage return or line feed character  (ASCII 32, 13, 10 respectively) at the end of the value.
If, for example, the output is:



TASK_ID
TASK_NUMBER
DUMP(TASK_NUMBER)




1
123ABC
Typ=1 Len=7: 49,50,51,65,66,67,13



Then you have a trailing carriage return (ASCII 13) character and you can remove it using:
UPDATE PA_TASKS
SET    task_number     = RTRIM(task_number, CHR(13)) -- Use CHR and the ASCII value
WHERE  PROJECT_ID      = :your_expected_project_id
AND    TASK_NUMBER     LIKE :your_expected_task_number || '%'
AND    CHARGEABLE_FLAG = 'Y';

Or,  alternatively, you can use REPLACE(task_number, CHR(13)) or TRANSLATE(task_number, 'A' || CHR(13), 'A')

As an aside, your procedure could be written using the column data-types and without the intermediate variable or nested PL/SQL blocks:
PROCEDURE GET_TASK_ID(
  P_TASK_NUMBER_IN IN  PA_TASKS.TASK_NUMBER%TYPE,
  P_PROJ_ID_IN     IN  PA_TASKS.PROJECT_ID%TYPE,
  P_TASK_ID_OUT    OUT PA_TASKS.TASK_ID%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
   SELECT TASK_ID
   INTO   P_TASK_ID_OUT
   FROM   PA_TASKS
   WHERE  PROJECT_ID      = P_PROJ_ID_IN
   AND    TASK_NUMBER     = P_TASK_NUMBER_IN
   AND    CHARGEABLE_FLAG = 'Y';
END;

fiddle
